# make multiple http calls synchronously in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, http

I am using AngularJs in my project. I have to make multiple http calls and then return the consolidated result to my view. How to achieve this using AngularJs?

Please let me know since I am not an expert in AngularJs and need a proper approach to solve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the promise API:

```
var wheatherPromise = $http.get(...);
var timePromise = $http.get(...);

var combinedPromise = $q.all({
    wheather: wheatherPromise,
    time: timePromise
})

combinedPromise.then(function(responses) {
    console.log('the wheather is ', responses.wheather.data);
    console.log('the time is ', responses.time.data);
});
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) for more details

Answer (score 0):

- make ur $http request in a seperated function or (AJS service is
  recommended).
- call that function in a for loop based on ur list
- declare a scope variable holds an empty array inside the function
- push response objects in the array

avoid defining  $http.get inside a for loop which cause unexpected behavior

Comment: Thanks for your answers But when calling the http, these calls will be asynchronous and the control will not wait for all the responses are filled inside the object.

Comment: for each request i'll store its response object in the array (no waiting) ,but the main concern is the .success callback function will create another thread which may call unexpected behavior if u do it  without separation of looping and requests.